# How do I switch between HTML5 canvases using Ionics ion-slides?

Tags: angular, html, ionic-framework, html5-canvas, ionic4

I'm writing an application in which I want to show different shapes drawn on an HTML5 canvas based on the slide I'm currently on.

So when the application loads I want to initialize say 2 slides, one with a triangle and one with a square and be able to use Ionics ion-slides to slide between them.

So in another component I use my canvas component like in the following to create the three tabs:

```
 <ion-slides id='slides'>
    <ion-slide *ngFor='let index of [0,1]'>
      <customCanvas [index]='index'></customCanvas>
    </ion-slide>
  </ion-slides>
```

My customCanvas.component.html only contains a canvas like:

```
<canvas id="canvas" width="300px" height="300px"></canvas>
```

And the customCanvas.component.ts intializes the canvas in:

```
  ngOnInit() {
    this.canvas = <HTMLCanvasElement>document.getElementById('canvas');
    var context = this.canvas.getContext("2d");

    //use the context to draw either a triangle/square
  }
```

As each component has an own canvas, my expectation would be that I would get two different canvas elements with the way I'm accessing them.
It seems however, that I always get the currently shown canvas and that first shape is overridden by the second.
When sliding to the other canvas, it is just the empty default canvas.

Any clues on how to access the "hidden" canvas would be appreciated and get that slider right would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per browser standards having multiple ids with the same name is valid, but it would not work the same when you query the DOM, it will always return the 1st occurrence of the `ID`. The problem over here is you're querying document using `canvas` id. Over here you can consider changing `id` to `class` selector.

And then while querying the DOM, limit it to a specific component using `this.elementRef.nativeElement`. Also use `ngAfterViewInit` lifecycle to make sure component DOM exist before doing any kind of DOM manipulations.

```
constructor(private elementRef: ElementRef) {}

ngAfterViewInit() {
    // You could also use Renderer2 API for SSR and WebWorker support
    this.canvas = this.elementRef.nativeElement.getElementByClassName('canvas');
    var context = this.canvas.getContext("2d");

    //use the context to draw either a triangle/square
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply but even without the elementRef.nativeElement restriction the     
document.getElementsByClassName("canvas")[0] yields undefined whereas getElementById yields the valid canvas. Any idea on that?

Comment: Okay, I got it to work using this.elementRef.nativeElement.querySelectorAll('canvas')[0];
The restriction using the ElementRef did the trick.
I still don't really understand why the getElementsByClassName returned undefined, though.

Comment: @fishishuntingsharks did you change the lifecycle method to `ngAfterViewInit`?

Comment: yes I did but the results for whether I did it in onInit or ngAfterViewInit were identical